# Getting error while trying to save the scraped data into a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I had **scraped** the website and now I want them to be saved as a csv file for that I wrote the script like this:

```
# Here using selenium for scraping
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import csv  

# the relevant url
url = 'https://web.bet9ja.com/Sport/SubEventDetail?SubEventID=76512106'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"c:/Users/SATYA/mysite/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
# name of csv file  
filename = "university_records.csv"
names = [
    item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SECQ.ng-binding")]
fields = print(names[0:2])
elements = [
    item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SEOddLnk.ng-binding")]
values = [
    item.text for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.SEOddsTQ.ng-binding")]
rows = print([values[0]+' '+elements[0], values[1]+' '+elements[1], values[2]+' '+elements[2]], [values[3]+' '+elements[3], values[4]+' '+elements[4], values[5]+' '+elements[5]])

# writing to csv file  
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:  
    # creating a csv writer object  
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)  
    # writing the fields  
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)  
    # writing the data rows  
    csvwriter.writerows(rows) 
    driver.quit()
```

The error is:

```
['1X2', 'Double Chance']
['1 3.60', 'X 4.20', '2 1.87'] ['1X 1.83', '12 1.19', 'X2 1.25']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 48, in <module>
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType
```

can anyone say where I am doing wrong in my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace:

`fields = print(names[0:2])`  with `fields = names[0:2]`

You have to remove `print` from rows variable also

`print` command just prints the given object to the stdout. It doesn't return any value.

Comment: @ Lovleen Kaur yes got it can you please help me with other small issue